# Select2 - Show/Hide div based on selection

Tags: jquery-select2

I am trying to have a div show if an option is selected using the Select2 plug in.

I tried using the following code but it does not work:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var h = $(".shipment-details--other-description");
  $("#shipment-details-select-pacakage-types").change(function() {
    if (this.checked && this.value == "Other") {
      h.show();
    } else {
      h.hide();
    }
  }).change()
});
```

The div is being hid but not being shown if the Other option is selected.

Is there a different way to do this with Select2?

**Edit:** Forgot to mention that this a multiple select field. Also, adjusted the code and took out the `this.checked` as that was for a check field.

Answer (score 0):

try to create a new css class, is-hidden{ display:none;}

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var h = $(".shipment-details--other-description");
  $("#shipment-details-select-pacakage-types").change(function() {
    if (this.checked && this.value == "Other") {
      h.addClass('is-hidden');
    } else {
      h.removeClass('is-hidden');
    }
  }).change()
});
```

Comment: Tried the above but did not work. Am able to hide the div but not show it. I am thinking it has something to do with the select value but not sure what.